# PostCSS and breakpoint Mixins

Tags: sass, postcss

recently i switched from SASS to PostCSS. However still cant figure out how to make breakpoint mixin with map-get (i insalled map-get plugin).

So this is SCSS version

```
@mixin bp-max($bp) {
  @media (max-width: map-get($bps, $bp)) {
    @content;
  }
}

$bps: (
  "mob": 480px,
  "tab": 768px,
  "desk": 1200px,
  "deskBig": 1600px,
) !default;
```

But as i can see map-get is not the same as for sass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the same switching process as you are, from scss to postcss, mainly to use also tailwindcss.

Anyway I found the solution to use similar mixins in postcss as those you mention in scss.

However you need to install several postcss plugins for that to work:

- postcss-nested
- postcss-simple-vars
- postcss-mixins
- postcss-map-get

That should allow you to use a similar approach, however the syntax changes significantly:

This is how your mixins will look like with postcss and these plugins (no 'quotes' in the breakpoint names, no parenthesis in the mixin definitions ...):

```
$breakpoints-up: (
  small: 440px,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1400px,
);
$breakpoints-down: (
  xsmall: 439px,
  small: 639px,
  medium: 1023px,
  large: 1399px,
);
/* xsmall < 440 < small < 640 < medium < 1024 < large < 1400 < xlarge */

@define-mixin breakpoint-up $size {
  @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints-up, $size)) {
    @mixin-content;
  }
}

@define-mixin breakpoint-down $size {
  @media (max-width: map-get($breakpoints-down, $size)) {
    @mixin-content;
  }
}
```

And when you want to use the breakpoints instead of @include, you need to use @mixin, like this:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  @mixin breakpoint-down medium {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```